# Runtime Error "9" Subscript out of range

Tags: vba, range, subscript

I have a great problem. I have a macro that does not run since the last week and I do not know why? I'm getting always the error: "Runtime Error 9 ...."

I know there must be a problem with the renames or arrays but I do not find anything. 
Could you please check this code, maybe you can find the problem.

Thanks in advance! 
Regards, Krisztian

It is just a part of the big macro.
The error is in the 8th row when "k" would be = "10"

Ubound is teoretically "9" (??)

EditRow(k) = EditRow(k) + (insdels * (k - 1))

```
'Populate input sheet
insdels = 0
For i = 1 To UBound(EditRow)
  If FAT_Blocks(i).Range_Name <> "Absent_from_BCM" Then   ' only process the blocks that were present
    k = FAT_Blocks(i).GPI_Block_Number 'ERROR***************************************************************************
    EditRow(k) = EditRow(k) + (insdels * (k - 1))

    For m = 1 To FAT_Blocks(i).Rows
      If FAT_Blocks(i).Data(m, 1) <> 0 Then ' ignore rows with zero cost/revenue in year 1
        If GPIsheet.Cells(EditRow(k), 2).Interior.ColorIndex <> new_CI Then
            new_InsDel (1)
            insdels = insdels + 1
            EditRow(k) = EditRow(k) + (k - 1)
        End If

        If FAT_Blocks(i).Row_Title(m) Like "*One Time*" Then
            y = 0
        ElseIf FAT_Blocks(i).Row_Title(m) Like "*Recurring*" Then
            y = 1
        Else
            y = 2
        End If
        With GPIsheet
           .Range("Original_Import_Data").Offset(EditRow(k) - 1, 0).ClearContents     ' clear any mung before updating
           ' fill the "new_CI" coloured cells on the left
           .Cells(EditRow(k), 2).value = BCMid & " " & FAT_Blocks(i).Row_Title(m)   ' row description
           .Cells(EditRow(k), 3).value = FAT_Blocks(i).Data(m, 1)                   ' unit value
           .Cells(EditRow(k), 4).value = change_pc(y)                               ' change %
           .Cells(EditRow(k), 5).value = change_year(y)                             ' change year
           .Cells(EditRow(k), 6).value = vol_driver(y)                              ' volume driver
           ' fill the grey stuff on the right
           With .Range("Original_Import_Data").Offset(EditRow(k) - 1, 0)
              .Cells(1, 1) = yr  ' Contract length
              .Cells(1, 2) = BCMid ' BCM unique id
               For j = 1 To yr
                 .Cells(1, 2 + j) = FAT_Blocks(i).Data(m, j) ' data for corresponding year
               Next
           End With
         End With
         EditRow(k) = EditRow(k) + 1
      End If
    Next m
  End If
Next i
```

Comment: use debug.print on both i and k and see if one of them goes beyond the range / array upper limit?

Comment: Thanks Alex for the quick answer, I'll check it on monday, at the work.